# Is there a way to prevent non-admin users from disabling Safari extensions?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

I would like to force non-admin users to keep a particular Safari extension enabled (for example, to apply limits to child accounts).  Is there some way to do so?

Comment: do you mean enable parental control, or are they to clever for that

Comment: No, the question is about Safari extensions, not parental controls.  That was just an example.

Comment: I understand, you want to prevent others from modifying the Safari extensions. So let my try to help you how to lock Safari settings from been changed.